# can somebody help me with a doubt in Elgg

Tags: ajax, elgg

Im facing a problem in elgg. Can somebody help me ?

I'm unable to make ajax calls in elgg

Comment: You'll need to be a lot more specific to allow us to help you. What are you trying to achieve? What have you done so far? What is the problem you're experiencing with your current solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an Elgg support forum -- you'll have better luck on the [community site](http://community.elgg.org), or on the Elgg developers mailing list (elgg-development@googlegroups.com).